# imagen beside a math

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, math-mode, circuitikz

how I can make me stay in the following way but instead of using $ using the command / begin {align} for me to number the mathematical formulas to reference them later?

```
 \begin{center} 
 \begin{tabular}{ll}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
            \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
            \coordinate (B) at (1.3,0);
            \coordinate (C) at (0,1.12);
            \coordinate (D) at (1.3,1.12);
            \draw[o-] (A)--(B) ;
            \draw[o-] (C)--(D) ;
            \draw   (1.3,1.12) to[resistor,label=\mbox{\textcolor{red}{$R$}}] (1.3,0);
            \draw [->,color=blue] (0.5,0.8) arc (90:-90:0.3cm);%
            \draw (0.5,0.5) node {\textcolor{blue}{$i$}}; \end{tikzpicture}
 &
\begin{tabular}{l}
$v_e=R i$ \\ \\
$v_e(s)=R I(s)$ \\ \\
\end{tabular}
% \caption{Resistencia}
 \label{fig:1.10}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

because when i try to use the next form i have a error with the compiler

```
\begin{center}%----figura de la Resistencia
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\begin{tikzpicture}
            \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
            \coordinate (B) at (1.3,0);
            \coordinate (C) at (0,1.12);
            \coordinate (D) at (1.3,1.12);
            \draw[o-] (A)--(B) ;
            \draw[o-] (C)--(D) ;
            \draw   (1.3,1.12) to[resistor,label=\mbox{\textcolor{red}{$R$}}] (1.3,0);
            \draw [->,color=blue] (0.5,0.8) arc (90:-90:0.3cm);%
            \draw (0.5,0.5) node {\textcolor{blue}{$i$}}; \end{tikzpicture}
 &
\begin{align}
v_e=R i$ \\
v_e(s)=R I(s)
\end{align}
% \caption{Resistencia}
 \label{fig:1.10}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Any suggestion??
Thanks

Comment: Please provide a *minimal*, *complete* version of your code; code snippets are not useful if you are using packages and libraries that you don't include in your snippet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use two side-by-side `minipage`s; I changed your code since you didn't provide a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits,arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{center} 
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
 \begin{tikzpicture}
            \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
            \coordinate (B) at (1.3,0);
            \coordinate (C) at (0,1.12);
            \coordinate (D) at (1.3,1.12);
            \draw[o-] (A)--(B) ;
            \draw[o-] (C)--(D) ;
            \draw (0.5,0.5) node {\textcolor{blue}{$i$}}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\begin{align*}
v_e &= R i \\
v_e(s) &= R I(s)
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Is it something like this what you are trying to achieve?